# How to remove debug app in circulation so that people can use signed apk

Tags: android

I circulated a debug app to many people and they have installed it. unfortunately admob is not working on debug app and only working on signed apk. How do I remotely  delete or deactivate the debug app in circulation and share a new signed apk? please help

Comment: If it is a web app and there is a way to show message, or you have implemented a notification system, you can notify users to install a new apk elsewhere I think there is no way.

Comment: If they installed it manually (sideloading), I don't think you can. After all, because it's not signed, you have no proof that you created the app. Each of your testers will have to uninstall the app manually before they can install the signed apk.

Answer (score 3):

there is no way to force any user to remove any app, obvious security reasons. only with root and some additional code which may be executed from third-party (e.g. request from server-side) - I doubt this is possible in your case

you have to notify somehow all your users that they must remove old version at first, then install new version (properly signed)